# Error java.lang.NullPointerException al enviar datos a la base de datos

Tags: java, sql-server, jsp

Estoy realizando un proyecto WEB en java, el problema esta cuando oprimo el botón de agregar, ya revise la conexion a la base de datos, si la realiza, lo hice en java swing y si inserta datos, revise el nombre de las caja de texto y estan escritos correctamente. Estoy utilizando boostrap, pero me indica que el error es productoDAO. Se los agradeceria mucho si me pueden ayudar por favor.
La linea 20 del DAO es: ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    Modelo.ProductoDAO.registrarUsuario(ProductoDAO.java:20)
    Controlador.Controlador.processRequest(Controlador.java:67)
    Controlador.Controlador.doPost(Controlador.java:104)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:652)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
```

Este seria mi controlador

```
 Producto p = new Producto();
ProductoDAO pDAO = new ProductoDAO();

protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    String accion = request.getParameter("accion");
    String menu = request.getParameter("menu");

    if (menu.equals("Inicio")) {

        // Redirreciona al inicio
        request.getRequestDispatcher("/Inicio.jsp").forward(request, response);

    }

    if (menu.equals("Producto")) {
        // Redirreciona a la pagina producto
        switch (accion) {

            case "Agregar":
                
                // Declaracion de variables
                String codigoProducto = request.getParameter("txtCodigo");
                String nombreProducto = request.getParameter("txtProducto");
                String precioProducto = request.getParameter("txtPrecio");
                String cantidadProducto = request.getParameter("txtCantidad");
                String estadoProducto = request.getParameter("txtEstado");
                
                // Instanciar a la clase con set
                p.setCodigoProducto(codigoProducto);
                p.setNombreProducto(nombreProducto);
                p.setPrecioProducto(Float.parseFloat(precioProducto));
                p.setCantidadProducto(Integer.parseInt(cantidadProducto));
                p.setEstadoProducto(estadoProducto);
                
                pDAO.registrarUsuario(p);

                break;

        }

        request.getRequestDispatcher("/Producto.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }
```

Este seria mi conexion

```
    public static Connection getConexion() {

    String urlConexion = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;"
            + "database=SistemaVentas;"
            + "user=sa;"
            + "password=admin;"
            + "loginTimeout=30;";

    try {

        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(urlConexion);
        return con;

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.toString());
        return null;
    }

}
```

Mi clase DAO

```
   PreparedStatement ps = null;
    int resultado = 0;

    public int registrarUsuario(Producto p) { // Parametro clase Usuarios.

     // Atributos de tabla utilizada, con sus atributos
    String sql = "INSERT INTO Producto(IDProducto, NombreProducto, Precio, CantidadProductos, Estado) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

    // Preparacion de Query.
    try {
        Connection con = getConexion();
        ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        ps.setString(1, p.getCodigoProducto()); // Usuario
        ps.setString(2, p.getNombreProducto()); // Contrasenia
        ps.setFloat(3, p.getPrecioProducto()); // Nombre
        ps.setInt(4, p.getCantidadProducto()); // idTipo
        ps.setString(5, p.getEstadoProducto());
        ps.executeUpdate();
        
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        System.err.println(ex);
    }

    return resultado;

}
```

EL JSP tengo escrito correctamente las cajas de texto en el controlador y nada, todo esta cuando oprimo el boton agregar

<%@include file="PaginaMaestra.jsp" %>

```
<div class="card col-sm-10">
    <div class="card-body">
        <form action="Controlador?menu=Producto" method="POST">
            <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="txtCodigo" placeholder="Código">
                <label for="floatingInput">Código</label>
            </div>

            <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="txtProducto" placeholder="Producto">
                <label for="floatingInput">Producto</label>
            </div>

            <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="txtPrecio" placeholder="Precio">
                <label for="floatingInput">Precio</label>
            </div>

            <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="txtCantidad" placeholder="Cantidad">
                <label for="floatingInput">Cantidad</label>
            </div>

            <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="txtEstado" placeholder="Estado">
                <label for="floatingInput">Estado</label>
            </div>
            <input type="submit" name="accion" value="Agregar" class="btn btn-info">
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Intenta poner esta declaración dentro del método: `PreparedStatement ps = null;` a ver qué pasa.

Answer (score 1):

En un principio afirmas que has comprobado que la conexión está establecida correctamente, que efectivamente inserta datos, que el formulario no tiene campos nulos y/o vacíos, etc. Bien. **Te recomendaría que comprobaras exactamente el valor de cada cosa ejecutándolo en modo debug.**

De todas formas, en primer lugar podrías establecer una pequeña comprobación antes de instanciar el **PreparedStatement**:

```
Connection con = getConexion();
if ( con != null ) {
   ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
   ps.setString(1, p.getCodigoProducto()); // Usuario
   ps.setString(2, p.getNombreProducto()); // Contrasenia
   ps.setFloat(3, p.getPrecioProducto()); // Nombre
   ps.setInt(4, p.getCantidadProducto()); // idTipo
   ps.setString(5, p.getEstadoProducto());
   ps.executeUpdate();
}
```

En caso de que la conexión no sea nula, solo puede ser nulo por último el **producto** que estás insertando, por el motivo que fuera. De no ser así, todas las comprobaciones que afirmas al inicio podrían estar mal comprobadas y realmente **algun objeto si estuviera siendo nulo**.

Comment: Efectivamente la variable con es nula, sabes como puedo resolver por favor.

Comment: Gracias por tu contribuciòn, te sugerimos revisar [answer], saludos.